# CSS searchbox not rendering as expected

Tags: css

Any idea why my search box comes out all buggy looking like this:

[image]

Instead of like this:

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <form class="searchform">
        <input class="searchfield" type="text" value="Search..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" />
        <input class="searchbutton" type="button" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

CSS

```
    #header {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header_content {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

#header_logo {
    padding-right: 20px;
    float:left;
}

.searchform {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
    *display: inline;
    border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
    padding: 3px 5px;   
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background: #f1f1f1;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ededed));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #ededed);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed'); /* ie7 */
    -ms-filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed'); /* ie8 */
}
.searchform input {
    font: normal 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.searchform, .searchfield {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
    width: 202px;
    border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.searchform .searchbutton {
    color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #494949;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 27px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    background: #5f5f5f;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9e9e9e), to(#454545));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9e9e9e,  #454545);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie7 */
    -ms-filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie8 */
}
```

Full demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/FBVL2/

Comment: The code posted does not match the code in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Specifically, you did not include the CSS code, which is the culprit here. And you did not specify why you expected the special rendering shown in the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.searchform` is not wide enough.

```
.searchform {
    width: 250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FBVL2/3/

Reason has something to do with CSS box model.

Comment: Lots of padding on the right.  You might want to bring that down a bit from 300.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the container to be the same size as the search field.  This means there's no space for anything else.  You need to have a the input be box `padding` + input `margin` + button `margin` + button `width`.

Set the `#searchform` to `250px` wide, and the input to `200px` wide.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FBVL2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The search form `input` takes up the whole box, this came out what I'd call perfect.

```
.searchform input {
    font: normal 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Not by default, it was actually explicitly set in css (mistakenly).

Comment: Could be :), loads of colory stuff there.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBVL2/4/).  The difference between your answer and mine, is my solution makes the box bigger, and yours makes the input smaller.  Depends on the goal, but both are useful :-)

Comment: OP has something to choose from :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just this:

```
.searchform, .searchfield
    background: #fff;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
    width: 202px;
    border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Just remove .searchform

```
.searchfield {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
    width: 202px;
    border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

For me with this changes is working well.